# ssl certificate renew and reimport to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have a quick question.
I have a domain name registered with godaddy, and I have a ssl certificate issued by godday.
It is set up for auto-renew one month later.
The web server is running on Amazon Web Service. so I imported the SSL certificate from godaddy from AWS Certificate manager.
My question is since the ssl will be automatically renewed by godaddy. 
Do I need to reimport it to AWS certificate manager?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need to reimport it to AWS Certificate Manager. You might want to consider switching to an AWS ACM issued SSL certificate, which would renew and update in your AWS account automatically. Also, AWS ACM issued SSL certificates are free.